# Create bitmap to compare two images by pixel

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare two images by pixel.
I have searched on Google about bitmap but I did not clear with it.

My code is showing error `Parameter is not valid`.

I have try this;

var a = new Bitmap(imageurl);

but it does not work.

I am also refer this site for image comparison:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/image-comparison-using-C-Sharp/

What I have tried:

but showing error on this line `parameter is not valid`.

```
var img1 = new Bitmap(fileone);
var img2 = new Bitmap(filetwo);
```

I have store path in this two variable like this,

```
fileone=C:\image\a.jpg:
filetwo=c:\image\b.jpg;

var img1 = new Bitmap(fileone);
var img2 = new Bitmap(filetwo);

if (img1.Width == img2.Width && img1.Height == img2.Height)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < img1.Width; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < img1.Height; j++)
       {
           img1_ref = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
           img2_ref = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();

           if (img1_ref != img2_ref)
           {
              count2++;
              flag = false;
              break;
           }

           count1++;
        }
        // progressBar1.Value++;
    }

    if (flag == false)
       Response.Write("Sorry, Images are not same , " + count2 + " wrong pixels found");
    else
       Response.Write(" Images are same , " + count1 + " same pixels found and " + count2 + " wrong pixels found");
}
else
   Response.Write("can not compare this images");

this.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you getting the error when compiling or when running your program? The code does seem fine so I would guess it is at runtime and that the values of fileone/filetwo are not correct (maybe not escaped properly?).

Comment: i have check fileone and filetwo store correct path and also images also available in that folder.

Comment: give us exception details if you see an error

Comment: [ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
   System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename) +375973
   validate.Day_8_campairTwoImageUpload.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\saisoftex\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\validate\validate\Day_8_campairTwoImageUpload.aspx.cs:120
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110

Comment: Your paths 'C:\image\a.jpg' probably need to be escaped 'C:\\image\\a.jpg' with extra \s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting error on

```
var img1 = new Bitmap(fileone);
```

most probably your fileone doesn't exists, please make sure that  `C:\image\a.jpg` exists.

Comment: i checked images are available in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> fileone=C:\image\a.jpg:
> filetwo=c:\image\b.jpg;
> ```

That's not valid C#.  And how you quote filenames is VERY important, because backslash is an escape character.

Perhaps your real code looks like

```
fileone="C:\image\a.jpg";
filetwo="C:\image\b.jpg";
```

Then `\b` is turned into a backspace character, not what you wanted.  You can use an @-literal to avoid escape processing:

```
fileone=@"C:\image\a.jpg";
filetwo=@"C:\image\b.jpg";
```